# SEO for landing page of three different language sites

Tags: seo, html, language, landing-page

I have three sites running under the main domain `example.com/en/` `example.com/ar/` `example.com/ur/`

And there is a main HTML landing page `example.com` which have some introduction in three languages and links to three sites. 
Now i want this landing page to have a good SEO. and i want this page to appear in search in three languages.
if someone searchs Arabic it should be in results with Arabic title and description, if someone searches in English it should response in English. 
Is it possible? or suggest me other way to make a landing page for these sites.

Comment: Are you using alternative on the head of the documents? are you using any kind of redirection on the server depending on the language? what system do you have for users to select the language? have you considered using country domains? Write as much information as you can with what you have done and you are willing to do

Comment: It is just a simple HTML page with links to all sites. i dont know about alternative. how to do this?

Comment: i dont have any server depending redirection.

Comment: System or language selection is simple. they just land on the page and select the language button, and the are redirected to the site.

Comment: i just have one domain with .com . i dont have country domains.

Comment: Here is the page is use as language selection. [nzahid.tk](http://nzahid.tk/) . on a test domain.

Comment: remember that all three sites have different languages and different data as well. it is not the translation.

Comment: You would need three separate landing pages, in their respective langue, for each of the above directories to be indexed under local versions of search engines like `Google.ae`.

Comment: is it possible to create just one landing page for all three sites with three languages in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can create a single landing page for all languages …

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Example.com</title>
</head>
<body>

  <article lang="en">
    <h1><!-- English site title --></h1>
    <p>…</p>
    <a href="/en/" hreflang="en">Visit the English site</a> 
  </article>

  <article lang="ar">
    <h1><!-- Arabic site title --></h1>
    <p>…</p>
    <a href="/ar/" hreflang="ar"><!-- site link in Arabic --></a> 
  </article>

  <article lang="ur">
    <h1><!-- Urdu site title --></h1>
    <p>…</p>
    <a href="/ur/" hreflang="ur"><!-- site link in Urdu --></a> 
  </article>

</body>
```

… but **you can’t control how search engines should display this page** in their SERPs. So they won’t necessarily hide content in languages other than the current localization.

It’s nothing different than a landing page that contains several sites in the same language. In your case, it only happens to be the case that all sites are in a different language.

In this example, I used the `lang` attribute to mark up the language of the content on the page, and the `hreflang` attribute to mark up the language of the target links.

Note that you only have one `title` element, so you can’t have a different title for each language (well, you could switch it with JavaScript, but search engines won’t recognize this). So the title should probably be something like your domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rel="alternate" hreflang="x"` annotation in your HTML `<head>` section.

Google has provided specific guidelines here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Answers your question precisely.

To know more about SEO for multilingual and multi-regional sites, see https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en&ref_topic=2370587

Comment: Although these links contain helpful information regarding languages and regions, it does not specifically address the questions being asked.

Comment: is it possible to create just one landing page for all three sites with three languages in it?

Comment: Zahid No, you need 3 landing pages, one for each language, with hreflang=en and so on.

@dan If he implements hreflang, there's a better chance that Google will be able to figure out the language in which the search term is being entered and display the appropriate landing page.

Comment: @Dumbosapiens OK, but it's better if you explain it to the OP so it addresses his questions ;-)

Comment: `hreflang`+`rel`-`alternate` is for translations, but the sites are *not* translations. So in this case only `hreflang` should be used.